# Return string in http get request Angular 6

Tags: angular, http, angular6

I have some problem `return`ing a string from my request.

```
getTest(id: string): string {
  let foo: string = '';
  this.service.testProfile(id).subscribe(
    response => {
      foo = response.body.foo;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  )
  return foo;
}
```

I want to init `foo` to my response. `foo` and then just to return new value of foo. Everything work but there is no result, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank

Comment: `foo= response.body.foo;` is executed AFTER the return statement. That's why  is always an empty string

Comment: The code you provided is in a service or in a component.?

Comment: @SandipJaiswal it's componennt

Comment: So why you are returning? Just assign in a property of your component. When component value will change your value will reflect on your DOM. Observables are asynchronous so if you will return then it will return a empty string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Use this implementation instead: `getTest(id: string): Observable<string> {
  return this.service.testProfile(id).pipe(map(response => response.body.foo));
}`

Comment: can you please add the code snippet for this.service.testProfile ? That is the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved with Promise

```
getTest(id: string): Promise<any>  {
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  this.service.testProfile(id).subscribe(
   response => {
    foo = response.body.foo;
   },
   error => {
    console.log(error);
   }
   )
  }
  )
 }
```

Thanks everybody !

Comment: Where does the variable "foo" come from in your code above?

Answer (score 0):

You return a string which must still be filled (and thus is empty) as the async code to do so hasn't completed yet by the time you return. 
What you should return is an observable and emit the right string on it in the `subscribe(...)` call.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this and try..

```
getTest(id: string): string {
  this.service.testProfile(id).subscribe(
    response =>  response.body.foo,
    error => {
      console.log(error);
      return '';
    }
  )
}
```